# How to Build a Keyword Historgam in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am using MongoDB 3.4 and PyMongo. I have a set of keywords:

```
keywords = [ 'bar', 'foo', ..., 'zoo' ]
```

I also have a collection:

```
docs = { 'data' : ' ... bar foo ... ',
         'data' : ' ... foo ... ',
         'data' : ' ... zoo ... ' }
```

I am looking for a PyMongo aggregation query which is going to give me a dict:

```
{ 'bar' : 0, 'foo' : 2, ..., 'zoo' : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything language specific about this, as the only solutions are either all aggregate or using mapReduce, where the latter is defined in JavaScript functions

Just setting up some sample data:

```
db.wordstuff.insertMany([
  { 'data': "foo brick bar" },
  { 'data': "brick foo" },
  { 'data': "bar brick baz" },
  { 'data': "bax" },
  { 'data': "brin brok fu foo" }
])
```

### Aggregation Framework

Then you can run the aggregation statement:

```
db.wordstuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "split": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$data", " " ] },
        "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this", ["bar","foo","baz","blat"] ] }
      } 
    }   
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$split" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$split", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }    
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": ["bar","foo","baz","blat"],
          "as": "d",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$data.k","$$d"] },-1] },
              "then": { 
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$data",
                  { "$indexOfArray": ["$data.k","$$d"] }
                ]
              },
              "else": { "k": "$$d", "v": 0 }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

In reality, all of the real work is done by this point:

```
db.wordstuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "split": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$data", " " ] },
        "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this", ["bar","foo","baz","blat"] ] }
      } 
    }   
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$split" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$split", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},
])
```

Which gives you output like:

```
{ "_id" : "baz", "count" : 1.0 }
{ "_id" : "bar", "count" : 2.0 }
{ "_id" : "foo", "count" : 3.0 }
```

So the real work here is being done by [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and that is the main dependency on using the aggregation framework, so you need MongoDB 3.4 at least in order to do this. The very simple premise is to [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) the words out individually as array members, then [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the content to match the input array of words to match.

That [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) uses [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/), which is another addition as of MongoDB 3.4 to match against each listed word. There are other operators that can do this with longer syntax, but we know we already need MongoDB 3.4 so this is the shortest syntax.

All that is really done after that is to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the matched array of words from each document, then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to obtain those matched words as a distinct list, along with the count of the occurrences.

That really is all there is to it from the main perspective of the database.

The following parts are actually "optional" since these are easy to reproduce in code, and probably look a lot clearer and cleaner by doing so. But just to demonstrate the newer operators that would require MongoDB 3.4.4 at least for the introduction of [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

Again the basics are that the next [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) "rolls up" the matched words from the cursor into an array within a single document. There is also a very specific key naming applied of `"k"` and `"v"` for later reasons.

Then you use a [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage since the content of the document returned is evaluated from an expression. This expression uses [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate over the "input array" of words and matches those to the entries created from the aggregation. This matching is done using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfAray/) do return the matched index of the compared value.

You use this within [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) as you either want to transform that value into a matched elment using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), or alternately recognize the index was not a match. This either returns the aggregated entry ( obtained from earlier matches ) or a "default" value of `0` for the given word.

The final part uses [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) which transforms an array of objects with properties `"k"` and `"v"` in to "key/value" pairs as an object.

So you can ask MongoDB to do it, but the data is actually reduced by the minimal pipeline as shown, so you may as well do it in client code. It's pretty simple, and for JavaScript you just do:

```
var words = db.wordstuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "split": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$data", " " ] },
        "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this", ["bar","foo","baz","blat"] ] }
      } 
    }   
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$split" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$split", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},
]).toArray();


var result = ["bar","foo","baz","blat"].map(
  w => ( words.map(wd => wd._id).indexOf(w) !== -1)
    ? words[words.map(wd => wd._id).indexOf(w)]
    :  { _id: w, count: 0 }
).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr._id]: curr.count }),{})
```

So if there is anything that's language specific at all, then that would be the part. So if you choose to run the aggregation at it's basics and process the resulting cursor, then the python code would be:

```
input = ["bar","foo","baz","blat"]

words = list(db.wordstuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "split": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$data", " " ] },
        "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this", input ] }
      } 
    }   
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$split" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$split", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},
]))

result = reduce(
  lambda x,y:
    dict(x.items() + { y['_id']: y['count'] }.items()),
    map(lambda w: words[map(lambda wd: wd['_id'],words).index(w)]
      if w in map(lambda wd: wd['_id'],words)
      else { '_id': w, 'count': 0 },
      input
    ),
    {}
)
```

And either method pulls out the same result:

```
{
    "bar" : 2.0,
    "foo" : 3.0,
    "baz" : 1.0,
    "blat" : 0.0
}
```

---

### MapReduce

The alternate case where you don't even have the minimum MongoDB 3.4.0 available is to use mapReduce for the process instead. Again, this needs to be sent to the server as JavaScript, which is generally represented within "strings" in most language implementations ( other than JavaScript itself ):

```
db.wordstuff.mapReduce(
  function() {
    this.data.split(' ')
      .filter( w => words.indexOf(w) !== -1 )
      .forEach( w => emit(null,{ [w]: 1 }) );
  },
  function(key,values) {
    return [].concat.apply([],
      values.map(v => Object.keys(v).map(k => ({ k: k, v: v[k] })))
    ).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{
      [curr.k]: (acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.k))
        ? acc[curr.k] + curr.v : curr.v
    }),{});
  },
  {
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "scope": { "words": ["bar","foo","baz","blat"] },
    "finalize": function(key,value) {
      return words.map( w => (value.hasOwnProperty(w))
        ? { [w]: value[w] } : { [w]: 0 }
      ).reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{}) 
    }
  }
)
```

And that gives you the same results and really does exactly the same thing. Just a little slower because MongoDB needs to evaluate and process the JavaScript as compared to using it's own native coded methods with the aggregation framework.